# Styling errors in the form

Tags: django, django-forms

There is the following `form`.

```
<form id="contact_form" class="get-in-touch-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1 class="title {% if component.css_title_style %}{{ component.css_title_style }}{% endif %}">
        {{ component.title }}
    </h1>
    <p class="subtitle {% if component.css_subtitle_style %}{{ component.css_subtitle_style }}{% endif %}">
        {{ component.description }}
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                {{ contact_form.name }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                {{ contact_form.email }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                {{ contact_form.phone }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
                {{ contact_form.text }}
                <img id="clip" src="{% static 'images/clip.png' %}" style="position: absolute; left: 95%; top: 5%;" onclick="document.querySelector('#id_file').click()">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper" style="display: none">
                {{ contact_form.file }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="custom-checkbox">
                        {{ contact_form.nda }}
                        <label for="checkbox1">Send me an NDA</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="/static/images/loader.svg" height="65" alt="Loading..." style="display: none;">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="green-button">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="{% static 'images/map_all.png' %}">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I `submit` it and `errors` occur, text is displayed near the field that generates the error in its usual form. How can I style this text? For example, to highlight this field somehow?

I tried to do this through `ajax`, but it didn’t work. When I try to send a form containing errors to the server, I immediately get an error (for example, this field is required) and accordingly it does not reach any styling.

Now the error output looks like this.

[image]

How can you style it this way?

[image]

Comment: That is not done by Django, but by your browser itself. If you want to turn it off, use the `novalidate` attribute in the HTML form tag.

Comment: This tag does'n work in `Safari`(

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 which tag? the **attribute** `novalidate` works in Safari.

Comment: @dirkgroten https://www.wufoo.com/html5/novalidate-attribute/

Comment: @pythoner note that it's actually quite useful to let the browser do some of the validation, it's faster for the user and offloads your server.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Safari 7??? That's years ago. Has been working at least since Safari 9. And it works for me right now on the page you shared (Safari 12).

Comment: As an option, I propose, when clicking on the submit, to check certain fields for validity, and if they are invalid, then display the appropriate stylized text. And if everything is ok, then send to the server already.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `novalidate` to `form` tag.
2. Add following block after your `input` fields.

`<div class="contact_form_name" style="font-size:15pt; position: absolute; right: 30px; top: 20px; color: #FD7900; display: none"></div>`

3. Add `jquery + ajax` code.

```
var frm = $('#contact_form');
frm.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each($("div[class^='contact_form_']"), function(ind, value){
        $(value).hide();
        $(value).prev().css('border', 'none')
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: '',
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.result == 'error'){
                $.each(data.response, function(key, value) {
                    $('.contact_form_' + key).css('display', 'block')
                    $('.contact_form_' + key).prev().css("border", 'solid #FD7900')
                    $('.contact_form_' + key).text(value)
                })
            } else {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

4. Add `view` function.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    contact_form = ContactFormForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if contact_form.is_valid():
        contact_form.save()
        return JsonResponse({})
    else:
        response = {}
        for k in contact_form.errors:
            response[k] = contact_form.errors[k][0]
        return JsonResponse({'response': response, 'result': 'error'})
```